# Dropdown menu disappearing when hovering over scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a scrollable dropdown menu using HTML and CSS. However, when you hover over the scroll bar the menu disappears. I have been trying to solve this issue for a while without results. I'm guessing it has something to do with the CSS. Any thoughts?

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working for me. (Firefox 51 on Linux.)

Comment: Not working on Chrome 55  Windows 10

Comment: Works in FF(41.0.2), Chrome (57.0.2) and safari (5.1.7) on Wondows 10

Comment: This code is working as expected for me in Windows 10 on Chrome 54, Firefox 51, Edge 38, and IE 11, IE 10, and IE 9.  (StackOverflow itself looks pretty bad in IE 9.)  Can you describe your setup better?

Comment: In Chrome 56, it seems the dropdown disappears when the scroll bar hits the top or bottom but is fine in between

Comment: The menu kept disappearing when I clicked but it works when I added a **.dropdown-content:active { display:block}**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't offer a clear explanation on why the posted code does not work cross browser (I wasn't able to find any browser/OS combo where it fails), I believe it could be improved.

- I'd replace `display` with `transform` as a state changing property (explanation below);
- I'd use `width` instead of `max-width` on `.dropdown-content`;
- I'd remove `height: auto` (it's bloat);
- I'd add a `margin-bottom` to it, for when it touches `<body>`s bottom, so the `box-shadow` doesn't get cut.
- based on @Derek's suggestion in the comments, I'd add in a combination of `:hover`, `:active` and `:focus` on both `.dropdown` and `.dropdown-content` that would keep the dropdown open. This will also greatly improve usability on touch based devices.

Besides not being mobile friendly (there's no `:hover` on touch devices), the current solution suffers on devices which feature narrow or very narrow scrollbars, because when the pointer leaves the element by  only `1px`, the dropdown is gone.

And that, from where I see it, is a major usability problem. In order to fix it, I propose a short delay in which the pointer could re-enter the element and re-activate the `:hover` state, without the dropdown being closed. In the code below I used a delay of `.6s`, for exemplification, which is way too much - a good (natural) value would sit between `.3s` and `.4s` - adjust it to your liking.

Contrary to popular belief, this can be achieved without using `JavaScript` if, instead of using `display` to switch the states of the dropdown, one would use an animatable property, such as `transform` and would also use the very handy `transition-delay` property.

**The principle:**

```css
.dropdown-content {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform .0s linear .6s;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-delay: .0s;
}
```

**The example:**

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  transform: scale(0);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 24x;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: transform .0s linear .6s;
}

.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-content,
.dropdown:active>.dropdown-content,
.dropdown:focus>.dropdown-content,
.dropdown>.dropdown-content:hover,
.dropdown>.dropdown-content:active,
.dropdown>.dropdown-content:focus {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-delay: .0s;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another net (and neat) advantage of this method is one could also animate the opening and closing of the dropdown, which is not possible when using `display`.

Answer (score 0):

It works here in Firefox, but I think the combination of `min-width: 160px;`, no `width` and `overflow-x: hidden;` might be the cause in other browsers. Try removing the overflow-x - it has no effect in this case anyway (since there is only a min-width, but the actual width can go beyond that without a limit)